# Set custom notification sound per contact regardless of app - Samsung Phone

Tags: notifications, adb

I own a Samsung phone (One UI 5.0 Android 13), and was trying to set a custom notification sound for a contact (technically a "room") in the [Element android app](https://github.com/vector-im/element-android).

In the process I found [this issue](https://github.com/vector-im/element-android/issues/169) where BillCarsonFr mentions that Android uses [Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels) since Android 8, which seems like it's supposed to let you set a custom sound for any notification channel.

I observed the notification sound picking process on other apps like my SMS App or another web-based messaging App that had built in options to change notification sounds, and both of them loaded up an interface that was clearly from the Settings app in Samsung, letting me choose a sound. It also claimed to be a setting located in "App Name" > Chats > "Room/Person's Name".

However, I could not find a way anywhere to open a Chats setting under any App within the Samsung Settings app. It feels very frustrating to know such an option is there somewhere but there's no visual way of reaching it.

So... **TL;DR:** Is there any way I can forcefully open this chat-specific Setting using either ADB, some specific android SDK code, or an already existing App someone made?

Comment: On Samsung, the per-app notification setting should be accessible from App Info - Notifications - Notifications categories. There are also [conversations](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/conversations) for Android 11 or above, but AFAIK, it's only created after enabling custom notifications for each contact from the app directly.

Comment: @AndrewT. you're right, notification categories does show the custom notification settings in apps where I've already previously configured a custom notification by being redirected through the app itself. Like you said, you can't add new people here, you have to go through the actual app. So unfortunately my question remains, can I bypass this somehow and create an entry without using the app itself. Thank you for the input 